# When trying to display contents of an array in a table, order is reversed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete beginner in coding and especially in JavaScript. My assignment tells me to use the `array.map()` to display the contents in an HTML table with added index.

```js
var txt = "";
var products = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var products2 = products.map(withIndex);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

function withIndex(value, index, array) {
    txt = ("<tr><td>") + (index+1) + " " + value + txt + ("</tr></td>");
}
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```

This works almost as wanted but the contents of the table are displayed in reverse order like:
5 five
4 four
3 three
2 two
1 one

I also don't fully understand the reason var txt = ""; is needed when using arrays.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First your code is generating something that looks like this

```
<tr><td><tr><td><tr><td></tr></td></tr></td></tr></td>
```

You are putting the previous code after the new one, but you are also putting it inside of the new td.

You are using map totally wrong.

```js
var txt = "";
var products = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var products2 = products.map(withIndex);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products2.join("");

function withIndex(value, index, array) {
    return "<tr><td>" + (index+1) + " " + value + "</td></tr>";
}
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```

to do it the way you were doing, you would want to use a forEach

```js
var txt = "";
function withIndex(value, index, array) {
  txt = txt + "<tr><td>" + (index+1) + " " + value + "</tr></td>";
}

var products = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var products2 = products.forEach(withIndex);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```

Comment: Rather than "totally wrong", perhaps elaborate a bit. It's not really clear what you've changed.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. It will honestly take me a while to digest this. I know this is supposed to be elementary but it's still crazy to me you can answer so fast. We've basically been left to our own devices to study from w3schools and this is the first time I've even heard of array.join().